# Laravel return object with ordered relation data

Tags: laravel

I have the following query to return my site news by ID with the the comments associated to this ID. I also return the user who commented.

```
return SiteNews::with('SiteNewsComments.user')->find($id);
```

My questios is:

1. How I can access and order my `SiteNewsComments` by `created_at` (desc)?

Answer (score 1):

[Eager load a relationship with constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
SiteNews::with(['SiteNewsComments.user' => function($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->find($id);
```